Ubuntu 24.04 - brscan-skey and libsane issue
I am working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04. I installed Brother drivers for printers and scanners. I used these Brother machines for the last 10 years with no issues on previous version of Ubuntu.
When I install brscan-skey it
pkg: brscan-skey: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 brscan-skey depends on libsane (>= 1.0.11-3); however:
  Package libsane is not installed.

Setting up brscan-skey (0.3.2-0) ...
apt-get install libusb-0.1-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 brscan-skey : Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.11-3) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I did the apt --fix-broken install but it doesn't solve the problem. Moreover
host:~#  dpkg --list libsane*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version                Architecture Description
+++-===================-======================-============-=========================================================>
ii  libsane-common      1.2.1-7build4          all          API library for scanners -- documentation and support fil>
ii  libsane-hpaio:amd64 3.23.12+dfsg0-0ubuntu5 amd64        HP SANE backend for multi-function peripherals
ii  libsane1:amd64      1.2.1-7build4          amd64        API library for scanners

Therefore, from what I understand I have libsane so what's the problem?

As with many things it seems like the driver is not ready for Ubuntu 24.04. Contact the vendor and see what they say.

I came across the very same error with Linux Mint 22 (which is based on Ubuntu 24.04).
This solution worked for me: I rebuilt 'brscan-skey-0.3.2-0.amd64.deb' - I removed the dependency 'libsane (>= 1.0.11-3)' from the package.
Commands to do so:
dpkg -x brscan-skey-0.3.2-0.amd64.deb brscan-skey
dpkg -e brscan-skey-0.3.2-0.amd64.deb brscan-skey/DEBIAN
sed -i  -e 's/, libsane (>= 1.0.11-3)//g' brscan-skey/DEBIAN/control
sed -i  -e 's/, libsane (>= 1.0.11-3)//g' brscan-skey/DEBIAN/control.tmp
dpkg-deb -b brscan-skey brscan-skey-0.3.2-0.amd64.deb

(Don't forget to backup the original 'brscan-skey-0.3.2-0.amd64.deb' before just in case something goes wrong!)

it sounds reasonable, it worked for me also, Tnx

Ideally, we would edit the Brother .deb package to depend on libsane1 rather than libsane, but that is not an option, so we still need a package or a link to a package named libsane.
You can download the .deb package for libsane 1.1.1-5 directly from Launchpad under the section "Downloadable files" and install.
Why: The newest versions of sane-backends only include libsane1 and no longer include libsane.  libsane was last included in the sane-backends-1.1.1-5 package (for Jammy Jellyfish)
